# Office 365 Sharepoint Upload Files to Documents Library

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to use the following code to add files to my document library on Sharepoint Office365 using web services.

```
public void SaveFileToSharePoint(string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                var copyService = new Copy { Url = "https://mydomain.com/_vti_bin/copy.asmx", Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain") };

                var destURL = "https://mydomain.com/Shared%20Documents/" + Path.GetFileName(fileName);

                string[] destinationUrl = { destURL };

                CopyResult[] cResultArray;

                var fFiledInfo = new FieldInformation { DisplayName = "Description", Type = FieldType.Text, Value = Path.GetFileName(fileName) };

                FieldInformation[] fFiledInfoArray = {fFiledInfo};

                var copyresult = copyService.CopyIntoItems(destURL, destinationUrl, fFiledInfoArray, File.ReadAllBytes(fileName), out cResultArray);
                var b = copyresult;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

I receive the error "Object Moved".  The URL loads the WSDL in the browser though.  If there is a better way to upload and get files from SharePoint on Office365 online I would entertain that as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

as the ASMX webservices are deprecated you should check out the "new" rest services of sharepoint. [ON MSDN you find information about it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/apps/jj164022.aspx)

Or you can use the Client object model which would be my favorite way. The following example shows basic usage, to connect to SharePoint online check out the following [link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2013-Hello-0fd15fbf/sourcecode?fileId=77290&pathId=933217996)

```
using(ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://yourURL"))
{
Web web = context.Web;
FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\myfile.txt");
newFile.Url = "file uploaded via client OM.txt";
List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);   
context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: I like the look of this solution but how is security handled? Thanks.

Comment: check out the second link of my answer, there is a complete example application, especially the class Tokenhelper should be of interest for you

Comment: Where do I get Microsoft.SharePoint.dll which I need for this solution.  I do not have SharePoint installed and cannot install the WSS on my Windows 7 machine to get it.

Comment: Try this download from microsoft http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585

Comment: However downside is that we cannot upload large files using this approach.

Comment: if you need large files you can use rest api: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/b8b45aa0-2718-4110-9188-78188d854988/sp-2013-online-client-object-model-limitation-3m-on-uploading-a-file-from-a-sharepoint-app?forum=appsforsharepoint

Answer (score 7):

Using roqz suggestions above, here is the ultimate solution I came up with to place files in the SharePoint 2013 Office 365 document library and to retrieve them by name:

```
public void SaveFileToSharePoint(string fileName)
{
    using (var context = new ClientContext("https://mydomain.com/"))
    {
        var passWord = new SecureString();
        foreach (var c in "MyPassword") passWord.AppendChar(c);
        context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("me@mydomain.com", passWord);
        var web = context.Web;
        var newFile = new FileCreationInformation {Content = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName), Url = Path.GetFileName(fileName)};
        var docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
        docs.RootFolder.Folders.GetByUrl("Test").Files.Add(newFile);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
    }
}

public void GetFileFromSharePoint(string fileName, string savePath)
{
    using (var context = new ClientContext("https://mydomain.com/"))
    {
        var passWord = new SecureString();
        foreach (var c in "MyPassword") passWord.AppendChar(c);
        context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("me@mydomain.com", passWord);
        var web = context.Web;
        var myFile = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents").RootFolder.Folders.GetByUrl("Test").Files.GetByUrl(fileName);
        context.Load(myFile);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        using (var ffl = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(context, myFile.ServerRelativeUrl))
        {
            using (var destFile = File.OpenWrite(savePath + fileName))
            {
                var buffer = new byte[8*1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = ffl.Stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    destFile.Write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error :Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=File Not Found.
  Source=Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream responseStream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse()