# Upload File To SharePoint Online(office 365) Library Invokes Error

Tags: c#, sharepoint, office365

How can one resolve this runtime error?

**Error**

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Library, Version = 14.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system can not find the file specified.

**CODE**

```
string destUrl = "URL";
string destFileUrl = destUrl  + "biblioteca" + "/text.txt";
using(SPWeb site = new SPSite(destUrl).OpenWeb())
{
    site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

    FileStream fileStream = File.Open("FILE" , FileMode.Open);

    site.Files.Add(destFileUrl, fileStream, true/*overwrite*/);

    fileStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: what're you using? SharePoint client object model SDK?

Comment: No, Just a Simple Windows Form Aplication Project

Comment: Then how do your program connect to SharePoint online?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me.

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("SHAREPOINT URL")) {
    SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in "PASSWORD".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("ACOUNT.onmicrosoft.com", passWord);
    Web web = clientContext.Web; 
    FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
    newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FILE);
    newFile.Url = NAMEFORTHEFILE;
    
    List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle("LIBRARY NAME");
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);

    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string fileName = @"C:\AddUser.aspx";
using (var context = new   ClientContext("https://yourdomain.com")) {
    var passWord = new SecureString();
    foreach (var c in "YourPassword") passWord.AppendChar(c);
    context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("YourUsername", passWord);
    var web = context.Web;
    var newFile = new FileCreationInformation {
        Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName),
        Url = Path.GetFileName(fileName)
    };
    var docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Pages");
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you encountered this error: The partner returned a bad sign-in name or password error. For more information, see Federation Error-handling Scenarios.

I have the following codes:

```
                NetworkCredential Cred = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Username"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"]);
                SecureString PassWord = new SecureString();

                foreach (char c in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"].ToCharArray()) PassWord.AppendChar(c);

                clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Username"], PassWord);

                Web web = clientContext.Web;

                clientContext.Load(web);
```

Answer (score -2):

You **cannot** use the server side object model to upload files to SharePoint Online.

One has to use the **Client Object Model** to upload files to SharePoint online.

More Info

[Office 365 Sharepoint Upload Files to Documents Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125529/office-365-sharepoint-upload-files-to-documents-library)

Comment: I have try to use the code give in the link that you post !
I can use it in a Windows form Aplication , or not ?

Comment: Yes you can use this code from windows application. You need to add reference to following dlls :           Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll                                           Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Silverlight.Runtime.dll

Comment: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Silverlight.Runtime.dll 
I dont have thsi dll
Just have
icrosoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll

Comment: That would work in this case. You don't need Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Silverlight.Runtime.dll

Comment: can you share the correct link where to download that library?